# Transform Map<String, Object> to Object using Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Map<String, Object> and I want to transform it to an Object.
Basically the Map will contain the following:

```
username xyz
password abc
```

I want to transform it to a SimpleUser object which has two fields: username and password.
The current code looks like this, but I was wondering if I could do the object initialization inside the Stream:

```java
Map<String, String> user = adapter
    .getSecret("abc")
    .orElseThrow()
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, v -> v.getValue().toString()));

return new SimpleUser(user.get("username"), user.get("password"));
```

Comment: If this map is for 1 user, why do you need stream to create a simple user?

Comment: does your map has only 2 entries ("username", "password")?

Comment: Seems like `return adapter.getSecret("abc").map(user -> new SimpleUser(user.get("username").toString(), user.get("password").toString())).orElseThrow();`

Comment: @WingKuiTsoi if there is another way to do it without streams that's also good, but I just want it to be clean and readble. Prasath yes it has

Comment: “*but I just want it to be clean and readble*”—then don’t add an entirely obsolete Stream operation. Use something like Eklavya has shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is one not good pratice but tricky way to put them all in one line. Use jackson objectMapper **only if** the SimpleUser (Object) field names are the same as the Map, i.e. username and password.

```
SimpleUser u = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(
adapter.getSecret("abc")orElseThrow().entrySet().stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, v -> v.getValue().toString()))
, SimpleUser.class);
```

And you will need this library.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For your reference.